# Exit R terminal by typing `exit`?

Tags: r, rprofile

Almost every tool I use can be exited from terminal by typing `exit`. But R, being "unique" requires I type `q()`.

Can I set-up something in `.Rprofile` to achieve this?

Comment: `exit <- function() q()`?

Comment: Thanks, but I want to skip typing `()` too. This requires `exit()` to work.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can add to your `.Rprofile`:

```
exit <- list()
class(exit) <- 'exiter'
print.exiter <- function(exiterObject){ q() }
```

which creates an object `exit`, assigns it the class `exiter`, and then overrides the `print` function to actually call `q()` by only typing `exit` (which would normally print the object).

Thanks to [this blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/what-no-parentheses/) for the hack.

Answer (score 5):

R has active bindings for this exact purpose:

```r
makeActiveBinding("exit", function() q(), .GlobalEnv)
```

Now getting `exit` from the global environment triggers a call to `q`. Hence any of the following statements will end the R process:

```r
exit
get("exit")
exit + 1
typeof(exit)
(function() exit)()
```

But this one will not:

```r
(function(exit) exit)(0)
```

`rm(exit)` deletes the binding.

You'll find more details, including other ways to interact with bindings (locking, accessing, assigning to, etc.), in `?makeActiveBinding`.